# How to remove the word `References` in the EndNote section of Cross-Reference

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

Using Aspose Word for JAVA `16.2.0- JDK 1.6`

Two Word document.[A.docx](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BdNYnJLv0_wU7Uml4g2ihhUkiJhvPPtrJ94TokYfxV0/edit?usp=sharing) and [B.docx](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PHGnD9Igzjej9AnxtrOHCUoTgsqiLOhY7Rhvgwyr-ZU/edit?usp=sharing), each word document contains cross-reference of type `EndNote` and `End of Section`.

Using Aspose to merge both the document (A.docx & B.docx) and moving all the `cross-reference` of type `EndNote` to the last page `EndNote` using below code.

```
Document destinationApsoseDocument=destinationDocument.getDoc();// Output.docx
moveEndNoteToEnd(destinationApsoseDocument);
for(Document document : mergingdocument){ // A.docx & B.docx
Document mergingDocument=document.getDoc();                       
moveEndNoteToEnd(mergingDocument);
destinationApsoseDocument.appendDocument(mergingDocument,ImportFormatMode.KEEP_SOURCE_FORMATTING);
}
AsposeUtil.convertNumPageFieldsToPageRef(destinationApsoseDocument);
destinationApsoseDocument.updatePageLayout();
destinationApsoseDocument.save(outputFileName); // Output.docx

    public void moveEndNoteToEnd(Document dstDoc) {
        dstDoc.getFirstSection().getPageSetup().getEndnoteOptions().setLocation(3);
        dstDoc.getFirstSection().getPageSetup().getEndnoteOptions().setNumberStyle(0);;
        dstDoc.getFirstSection().getPageSetup().getEndnoteOptions().setStartNumber(1);
        dstDoc.getFirstSection().getPageSetup().getEndnoteOptions().setRestartRule(0);
    }
```

The cross-reference at `EndNote` of *A.docx* moved to to the `End of Document` `EndNote` that is *B.docx* and *A.docx* & *B.docx* are merged.-*This is expected and working fine*.

How to remove the word text **Reference** from *A.docx* after merging both the document ?

Note:

The reference are moved to `End of Document` but the word text **Reference** remains as it is.It is not getting removed.

Comment: It is difficult to answer the question without sample document. I would recommend you to post the question in the Aspose.Words support forum and attach sample documents there https://forum.aspose.com/c/words.

Comment: @AlexeyNoskov  Added Aspose.Words support forum  (https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-to-remove-the-word-references-in-the-endnote-section-of-cross-reference/213650)

Comment: If this is simple text, then you can use Find/Replace to remove it or use IReplacingCallback https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.replacing/ireplacingcallback to locate and remove the paragraph with text.

Comment: @AlexeyNoskov  I tried using the code `mergingDocument.getRange().replace("References", "", true, true);` but the code is replacing all the text **References** in the entire word file. In my case I want remove only the text **References** from all the pages of the document except the last page. As we are moving the  `EndNote` cross-reference to the last page. So last page **References** text should display.

Comment: I think you can replace work Reference before merging document using backward replace direction and by replacing only the first occurrence.